# useEffect for componentDidMount dependency

Tags: reactjs

1. I use useEffect for using only once when componentDidMount.
2. I reuse `requestPatientsApi` in the functional component.
3. Adding all dependencies in useEffect's second parameter occurs infinity rendering.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    requestPatientsApi();
  }, []);

  const requestPatientsApi = async (skip: number = 0, limit: number = 100) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await get<AxiosResponse<PatientApi>>("/patient", { skip, limit, requester: "admin" });

      setPager({
        ...pager,
        totalItems: data.totalCount
      });
      props.setPatients(refinedPatients(data.items));
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  };
```

**1. How to avoid NO.3's infinity rendering?**

**2. Is there are any ways to reuse `requestPatientsApi` avoiding NO.3?**

Comment: You can add additional useEffect hooks with different dependencies.

Comment: Is there any special use case where you want to reuse requestPatientApi? The reason I'm asking this question is because you can reuse "UseEffect" hook with different parameters passed as second argument. So in that manner you'll be reusing your method.

Answer (score 1):

The missing dependency warning just prompts you to add the dependency in dependency array in case you have missed it but since you are entirely sure that you only want to execute the code once on component mounting you can disable the warning using `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    requestPatientsApi();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
    requestPatientsApi();
  }, toggle);
```